# Capturar Campos Customizados(custom fields) da API do Trello

Tags: api, trello

Senhores, estou fazendo um sistema que possui integração com o Trello.
Ao realizar o seguinte comando HTTP:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://api.trello.com/1/cards/ID_CARD?key=MINHA_KEY&token=MEU_TOKEN'
```

Me é retornado o json corretamento no formato abaixo:

```
{
  "id": "560bf4dd7139286471dc009c",
  "badges": {
    "votes": 0,
    "viewingMemberVoted": false,
    "subscribed": true,
    "fogbugz": "",
    "checkItems": 0,
    "checkItemsChecked": 0,
    "comments": 0,
    "attachments": 2,
    "description": false,
    "due": null,
    "dueComplete": false
  },
  "checkItemStates": [

  ],
  "closed": false,
  "dueComplete": false,
  "dateLastActivity": "2017-06-26T17:39:49.583Z",
  "desc": "",
  "descData": null,
  "due": null,
  "email": null,
  "idBoard": "560bf4298b3dda300c18d09c",
  "idChecklists": [

  ],
  "idList": "560bf44ea68b16bd0fc2a9a9",
  "idMembers": [
    "556c8537a1928ba745504dd8"
  ],
  "idMembersVoted": [

  ],
  "idShort": 9,
  "idAttachmentCover": "5944a06460ed0bee471ad8e0",
  "manualCoverAttachment": false,
  "labels": [
    {
      "id": "560bf42919ad3a5dc29f33c5",
      "idBoard": "560bf4298b3dda300c18d09c",
      "name": "Visited",
      "color": "green",
      "uses": 15
    }
  ],
  "idLabels": [
    "560bf42919ad3a5dc29f33c5"
  ],
  "name": "Grand Canyon National Park",
  "pos": 16384,
  "shortLink": "nqPiDKmw",
  "shortUrl": "https://trello.com/c/nqPiDKmw",
  "subscribed": true,
  "url": "https://trello.com/c/nqPiDKmw/9-grand-canyon-national-park"
}
```

Porém possuo um campo customizado nos meus cards, utilizando o plugin [custom filds](http://info.trello.com/power-ups/custom-fields) e o mesmo não é retornado na requisição acima.

Segue um exemplo do meu card:

[image: O campo HST é meu campo customizado]

Já tentei utilizar a opção capturar o [plugin data](https://developers.trello.com/reference/#cardsidplugindata), porém também não me é retornado nada referente a este campo.

Quem puder dar essa força fico muito grato.